# php: issue with the output of var_dump($this)

Tags: php

```
<?php
class A {
    var $name= 'A';
    function main($objC){
        var_dump($this);B::request('init', $objC);
    }

}
class B {
    var $name= 'B';
    function request($func, $objC){
        if (method_exists($objC, $func)){
            var_dump($this);$objC->$func($this);
        }
    }

}
class C {
    var $name= 'C';
    function init($pobj){       
        var_dump($this);
    }
}
$objA =  new A;
$objB = new B;
$objC = new C;
$objA->main($objC);
```

Output:

```
object(A)[1]
  public 'name' => string 'A' (length=1)

object(A)[1]
  public 'name' => string 'A' (length=1)

object(C)[3]
  public 'name' => string 'C' (length=1)
```

I thought `$this` in `Class B` always means the object of that `Class B`. But seems not, can anyone explain: why `var_dump($this);` in `class B`, outputs below result not `object(B)`?

```
object(A)[1]
      public 'name' => string 'A' (length=1)
```

Comment: `B::request` is a `static` call, not a call to any instance of `B`, so the var_dump($this) from `B` has no contect of `B` being $this

Comment: @MarkBaker oops removed my comment about `static`, thought the question was why `$this` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this with full error logging enabled, it will explain why:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method B::request() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /php/tests/o2.php on line 6

So basically, use of $this in a statically-called method is meaningless, so PHP actually tries to apply a context.... and looks like it applies $this from the calling method

Comment: "$this in a statically-called method is meaningless" not always. The error is about incompatible context. If the context is the same, no error will be triggered afaik.

Comment: True: if the context is the same (i.e. I have method `request` in class A that references $this, and I call it statically from another method in A) then I don't get such a warning because the context isn't incompatible

Comment: I think my point is still valid though: because the context isn't compatible (ie there isn't an instance of B within the call hierarchy that can be referenced) then it's falling back to the previous (incompatible) context. Whatever the case, I wouldn't recommend it as good coding practise.

Comment: Thanks. it is helpful. BTW, how to  run this with full error logging enabled?